# QTreewidget change row height to keep aspect ratio

Tags: qt, pyside, aspect-ratio, qtreewidget

I want to make a icon and text view with QTreeWidget. Icon would be column 0 and text would be column 1. And I hope to keep aspect ratio when I resize the column 0. At this moment, I can adjust each row heights to match the icon width using **sizeHint** of the **QStyledItemDelegate**. But it works when show up at the first time, and expand the rows. How can I resize the height of each rows automatically when resize the column width?